# Is there a transcription of the exact chords of this recording?

Tags: piano, jazz, transcription

I've been listening to this recording of Dave McKenna for months now, and I've been stuck trying to learn/figure out the exact chords he's playing at around 40:30 to around 41:20. I have a very good ear, but not quite good enough to be able to pick out the *precise* chords--I mean I've gotten *some* of them, but not all--and so a transcription would be helpful. Does anyone know if a transcription even exists for this recording?

https://soundcloud.com/corte-swearingen/toulouse-4-24-1999-set1